# Exporting elasticache data to localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

We have one redis server running on aws and we would like to export data from redis to localhost. Is there any way I can export all data from aws to localhost?

If I run `BGSAVE` command from `redis-cli` then where is that data stored? Is is possible to download data to localhost after running `BGSAVE` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you setup elasticache you can configure an S3 bucket for saves.

Comment: There is no other way than s3 ? Will `BGSAVE` save data to s3 if configured.